# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to scrape a [website](https://ma.mohw.gov.tw/masearch/) and get the content of it with selenium.

**Brief intro of this website**: User Fills in the hospital name and maybe more information like city and zip, then press button and get the code and address of the hospital. (approximate string matching) Unfortunately it only provides Chinese version. If you want to make a test, you may just put **台大** in the top yellow field and complete the captcha, then press the yellow button in the bottom.

I have a list of hospital and try to fetch the information of all these hospitals, here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import ddddocr
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('hos.csv')

code_list = []
name_list = []
address_list = []

for i in range(len(df)):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('https://ma.mohw.gov.tw/masearch/')

    img = browser.save_screenshot('mohw.png')
    element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageCheck"]')
    left = element.location['x']
    right = element.location['x'] + element.size['width']
    top = element.location['y']
    bottom = element.location['y'] + element.size['height']

    image = Image.open('mohw.png')
    image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    image = image.convert("RGB")
    image.save(f'C:/Users/jlee72/Desktop/Hos/selenium + captcha/{i}.jpg')               
    print(f'{i}.jpg')

    ocr = ddddocr.DdddOcr()  #use this package to pass captcha
    with open(f'{i}.jpg', 'rb') as f:
        img_bytes = f.read()
    res = ocr.classification(img_bytes)
    print(res)

    try:

        Institution_name = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBAS_NAME"]')
        Institution_name.send_keys(df['New_Name'][i]) 

        Institution_code = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1"]') 
        Institution_code.send_keys(res) 

        login = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch"]')
        login.click()  

        time.sleep(10)
        
        detail = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gviewMain_ctl02_HlBAS"]')   #I get the error here
        
        detail.click()   
    
    except:
        code_list.append("Pass")
        name_list.append("Pass")
        address_list.append("Pass")
```

Somehow when I run the code here `detail = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gviewMain_ctl02_HlBAS"]')`, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gviewMain_ctl02_HlBAS"]"}
```

I've tried to change the error code from

```
detail = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gviewMain_ctl02_HlBAS"]')
```

to

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gviewMain_ctl02_HlBAS"]'))).click()
```

but still fail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete solution, and You can also make your code more precise like below:

```
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
import ddddocr
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

df = pd.read_csv('hos.csv')
# df = pd.DataFrame({"New_Name": ["彰化基督教醫院", "高雄長庚紀念醫院", "奇美醫院"]})
code_list = []
name_list = []
address_list = []

chrome_options = Options()
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

for i in range(len(df)):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('https://ma.mohw.gov.tw/masearch/')
    
    captcha = browser.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageCheck")
    captcha.screenshot(f'captcha_{i}.png')
    ocr = ddddocr.DdddOcr()
    with open(f'captcha_{i}.png', 'rb') as f:
        img_bytes = f.read()

    res = ocr.classification(img_bytes)

    # fill the hospital name
    Institution_name = browser.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtBAS_NAME")
    Institution_name.send_keys(df['New_Name'][i])

    # Fill the captcha and enter
    Institution_code = browser.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1")
    Institution_code.send_keys(res.upper())
    Institution_code.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    sleep(2)

    # click to Inquire
    login = browser.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSearch")
    login.click()
    sleep(1)

    # when the search/inquery returns the data
    try:
        detail = browser.find_element(By.ID, "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gviewMain_ctl02_HlBAS")
        detail.click()
        sleep(4)

    #otherwise
    except NoSuchElementException:
        code_list.append("Pass")
        name_list.append("Pass")
        address_list.append("Pass")
```

I hope it helps you, and this code can be further optimized if you want.

Comment: as you can see, for example, there is an option in selenium to take screenshots of a specific web element/tag.

Comment: Thank you Ajeet, your script solves the error and only need minor adjustments to fit in my request.

Comment: it's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
element = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageCheck')
```

Comment: I probably didn't make it clear enough - the error occurs when I try to click a button for more details, instead of checking the image.